# jQuery UI Draggable-Droppable overflow:visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, overflow, draggable

Sadly, I am unable to provide any JSFiddle for this issue, as I cant seem to reproduce it outside my project.

I have a container where there are some boxes, that can be arranged using drag and drop, by utilizing jQuery UI. The problem is, that the container is `overflow:auto;` but it needs to be `overflow:visible;`, but if I do that, jQuery UI malfunctions. When a box drag is initiated, it will immediatly jump up aproximately  400-500px.

This is how the draggable is created:

```
        $(".draggable").draggable({
            revert: 'invalid', // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
            containment: '#editContainer', // stick to demo-frame if present
            helper: 'original',
            cursor: 'move'
        });
```

Is this a bug with jQuery UI, or can this be fixed on my end?

I apologize for the lack of source code.

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with scrollTop on the container or a parent of it or perhaps the offset of your container element

Comment: Can you give us a link to your project?

Comment: Im afraid I am unable to - we've moved past this (dont think we ever solved it though), sorry.

Comment: If you can't recreate the problem outside of your project, clearly you've isolated where the problem lies.